# c++ trying to change local variable outside of function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ### write myFunction() ###

// ###

int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    myFunction(x);
    cout << "The Number + 1 is " << x;
}
```

I know I'm supposed to change x to x++, but how do I do so in myFunction() when x is a local variable in main()?

Comment: This question clearly suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are trying do something most probably you should not. If you will provide information what problem this code should solve you will get better solution. Sadly you already have answer for your bad approach.

Answer (score 3):

In c++, you can pass a variable by `reference` to a function, this means that you will access and write the actual variable from the function and not a copy of the variable :

```
myFunction(x); // doesn't change

void myFunction(int& x) // note the "&" (it means that x is a "reference" to an int)
{
    ++x;
}
```

[This article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/references/) describes well the "reference" thing.

As @0x5453 mentioned, a better approach would be to return the incremented integer from the pointer and assign it to a variable in the main, assuming you are allowed to do it.

```
x = myFunction(x);

int myFunction(int x)
{
    return ++x;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you could pass by value but then `return x` and assign `x` to that result inside of `main`.  (I tend to prefer this over reference parameters because it makes it clear at the call site that the value is potentially changing.)

Comment: I understood that the `myFunction(x)` line had to stay the same; but assuming it's possible to get the variable back, I think your way is better. I'll edit the post